# Unable to deploy large solana programs on devnet

Tags: solana-program, transactions, deploy

I have a very large solana program that I want to deploy on devnet but everytime I run the anchor deploy command all the available retries end and the transaction is never submitted. Is there any way I can deploy the program on devnet and subsequently on mainnet. The program deploys fine on localnet but I guess that is to be expected. Below is the error I get whenever I try to deploy the program.

```
tusharsahoo@Yudizs-Mac-mini-3 solana-contract % anchor deploy                                      
Deploying cluster: https://api.devnet.solana.com
Upgrade authority: /Users/tusharsahoo/.config/solana/id.json
Deploying program "market"...
Program path: /Users/tusharsahoo/Documents/GitHub/solana-contract/target/deploy/market.so...
Blockhash expired. 4 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 3 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 2 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 1 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 0 retries remaining
=============================================================================
Recover the intermediate account's ephemeral keypair file with
`solana-keygen recover` and the following 12-word seed phrase:
=============================================================================

=============================================================================
To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the
[BUFFER_SIGNER] to `solana program deploy` or `solana program write-buffer'.
Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the
[BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to `solana program close`.
=============================================================================
Error: Data writes to account failed: Custom error: Max retries exceeded
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the Solana cli are you using?

There was an issue with earlier version of Solana 1.16 [GH issues linked here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/32595), but it was fixed.

solutions:

1. upgrade to the latest Solana cli versions `solana-install update`
2. downgrade to earlier versions `solana-install init 1.14.20`

Comment: Thanks man upgrading it solved the issue. Actually I started Solana development around the start of August this year so I had no idea deploy transactions happened so fast here.